# Update text printed in console

Tags: node.js, typescript, asynchronous, logging, mutex

I am creating a CLI program in ts and my commands are writing the progress to the console. I would like to make this prettier by avoiding writing several lines like this:

```
Starting microservice api-gateway 
Microservice api-gateway started ✅

Starting microservice Agenda 
Microservice Agenda started ✅

Starting microservice Device 
Microservice Device started ✅
...
```

and just rewriting over the first line to modify the emoji :

```
Starting microservice api-gateway  -> Starting microservice api-gateway ✅
Starting microservice Agenda  -> Starting microservice Agenda ✅
Starting microservice Device  -> Starting microservice Device ✅
...
```

I managed to implement a first version:

```
process.stdout.write("Starting microservice api-gateway ")
# make something
process.stdout.moveCursor(0,-1)
process.stdout.write("✅")
```

this code work perfectly but have one problem: nothing else should be written to the console between the two functions.

So I managed to implement a second version for handling this. This version use a global variable to store each log that is printed to a table:

writeLog.ts

```
/**
 * Writes a log to the console and returns the index of the log
 * @param log The log to write
 * @return {number} The index of the log
 */
export default function writeLog(log: string): number {
    process.stdout.write(log);

    let newLog: Log = {
        log: log,
        cursorPos: {
            x: process.stdout.rows,
            y: process.stdout.columns
        }
    };

    let index = global.logs.push(newLog);
    process.stdout.write("\n");
    return index - 1;
}
```

rewriteLog.ts

```
/**
 * rewrite a log in the console
 * @param index The index of the log
 * @param log The new log
 */
export default function rewriteLog(index: number, log: string) {
    let row = global.logs.length - index;
    let col = global.logs[index].cursorPos.y;

    let pos = {
        row: process.stdout.rows,
        col: process.stdout.columns
    }

    process.stdout.moveCursor(-col, -row);
    process.stdout.clearLine(1);
    process.stdout.write(log + "\n");


    process.stdout.moveCursor(
        pos.col - col,
        pos.row - row
    );

    global.logs[index].log = log;
}
```

These two functions allow me to write a log and rewrite it. It works correctly except in two cases: if they are called asynchronously, or if they are called too quickly.

for the too quickly call, my research leads me to the `process.stdout.write()` and `process.stdout.moveCursor()` functions which contain a callback parameter which implies that the function is not synchronous, so it is possible that I move the cursor again BEFORE the first has finished writing or even started.

For the second problem it's pretty much the same, there is only one cursor and I want it to be in several places at the same time, to overcome this problem I looked if it was possible to ensure that a function can only be used by one process at the time and to pause everything else, which breaks the asynchronous principle but I base myself on the principle of mutexes in cpp for example. Unfortunately I couldn't find anything about it.

Comment: You may want curses/blessed/etc instead.

Comment: I thought of curses but the problem is that I am developing a CLI, curses would surely be an alternative for a program running continuously with a menu, etc. But my code is made to be re-executed for each command